# Input a vector to a transfer function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, vector

I have a transfer function in matlab, and I want to give it this function as an input vector: 
g(t) = 1 for t<=40sec and g(t) = -2 for t>40 sec.
I already created the time vector.
How do I proceed in writing g(t)?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

You will want your `g` to be of same length as `t`, so lets initialize it to a vector of zeros:

```
g = zeros(size(t));
```

We get a vector of same length as `t`. We now want to set all indices of `g` where `t <= 40` to `1`. Luckily, Matlab supports logical indexing, so we can just go ahead and do this:

```
g(t <= 40) = 1;
```

Analogue to values where `t <= 40`, we do the same for `t > 40`:

```
g(t > 40) = -2;
```

You may want to consult the Matlab documentation on logical indexing. In general, the documentation for Matlab isn't half bad, so that would be a good place to start if you face beginner problems such as this.

Comment: `size()` function is more appropriate, because if `length()` function were be used, `g` would be square matrix, not a vector.

Comment: To add to this, use [`lsim`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/lsim.html) to feed `g(t)` to your transfer function